# How to simulate GPSStatus satellites in android emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, gps

I checked the .GPX file but there is no information about satellites stats.  How could we test it with no real device?

To get satellites with follwing code:

```
GPSStatusView gpsStatusView = new GPSStatusView(this);
GpsStatus status = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);

Iterable<GpsSatellite> stats = status.getSatellites();
```

Answer (score 0):

A gpx file is not build for simulating advanced gps data.
It is a sequence of locations delivered by a navigation device like a GPS receiver. With the possibility of custom extension.

For simulating GPSStatus you would need a simulator based on NMEA format.
If that is not available, you could test it from a unit test:

Introduce an own locatgoin manager in your app, where normaly android would send GPS datat to. However In your test, you send that data with the GpStatus you like.